Discrepancy between Python and R calculation of a robust covariance matrix
I am currently developing a statistical package in Python using R code as a reference, and I've noticed different results between the two programs when calculating a robust covariance matrix in Python versus R.
Using the following code with equivalent input data (x) in Python:
# dummy data
x = np.array([
    [0.5488135, 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318],
    [0.4236548, 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773],
    [0.96366276, 0.38344152, 0.79172504, 0.52889492],
    [0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606, 0.0871293],
    [0.0202184, 0.83261985, 0.77815675, 0.87001215],
    [0.97861834, 0.79915856, 0.46147936, 0.78052918],
    [0.11827443, 0.63992102, 0.14335329, 0.94466892],
    [0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.77423369],
    [0.45615033, 0.56843395, 0.0187898, 0.6176355],
    [0.61209572, 0.616934, 0.94374808, 0.6818203],
    [0.3595079, 0.43703195, 0.6976312, 0.06022547],
    [0.66676672, 0.67063787, 0.21038256, 0.1289263],
    [0.31542835, 0.36371077, 0.57019677, 0.43860151],
    [0.98837384, 0.10204481, 0.20887676, 0.16130952],
    [0.65310833, 0.2532916, 0.46631077, 0.24442559],
    [0.15896958, 0.11037514, 0.65632959, 0.13818295],
    [0.19658236, 0.36872517, 0.82099323, 0.09710128],
    [0.83794491, 0.09609841, 0.97645947, 0.4686512],
    [0.97676109, 0.60484552, 0.73926358, 0.03918779],
    [0.28280696, 0.12019656, 0.2961402, 0.11872772]
])

# fit mcd
mcd = MinCovDet().fit(x)

# define robust covariance variable
x_cov = mcd.covariance_

and in R:
# dummy data
x <- matrix(c(
  0.5488135, 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318,
  0.4236548, 0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773,
  0.96366276, 0.38344152, 0.79172504, 0.52889492,
  0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606, 0.0871293,
  0.0202184, 0.83261985, 0.77815675, 0.87001215,
  0.97861834, 0.79915856, 0.46147936, 0.78052918,
  0.11827443, 0.63992102, 0.14335329, 0.94466892,
  0.52184832, 0.41466194, 0.26455561, 0.77423369,
  0.45615033, 0.56843395, 0.0187898, 0.6176355,
  0.61209572, 0.616934, 0.94374808, 0.6818203,
  0.3595079, 0.43703195, 0.6976312, 0.06022547,
  0.66676672, 0.67063787, 0.21038256, 0.1289263,
  0.31542835, 0.36371077, 0.57019677, 0.43860151,
  0.98837384, 0.10204481, 0.20887676, 0.16130952,
  0.65310833, 0.2532916, 0.46631077, 0.24442559,
  0.15896958, 0.11037514, 0.65632959, 0.13818295,
  0.19658236, 0.36872517, 0.82099323, 0.09710128,
  0.83794491, 0.09609841, 0.97645947, 0.4686512,
  0.97676109, 0.60484552, 0.73926358, 0.03918779,
  0.28280696, 0.12019656, 0.2961402, 0.11872772
), nrow = 20, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

# fit mcd
x.mcd <- covMcd(x)

# define robust covariance variable
x_cov <- x.mcd$cov

I get very different values for x_cov. I am aware that there is stochasticity involved in each of these algorithms, but the differences are way too large to be attributed to that.
For example, in Python:
x_cov = array([[ 0.06669275,  0.01987514,  0.01294049,  0.0235569 ],
              [ 0.01987514,  0.0421388 , -0.00541365,  0.0462657 ],
              [ 0.01294049, -0.00541365,  0.06601437, -0.02931285],
              [ 0.0235569 ,  0.0462657 , -0.02931285,  0.08961389]])

and in R:
x_cov =             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
          [1,]  0.15762177 0.01044705 -0.04043184 -0.01187968
          [2,]  0.01044705 0.09957141  0.03036312  0.08703770
          [3,] -0.04043184 0.03036312  0.06045952 -0.01781794
          [4,] -0.01187968 0.08703770 -0.01781794  0.16634435

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I can't seem to figure out the discrepancy. Have you run into something similar or do you perhaps have any suggestions for me? Thanks!

Have you gone through the arguments for each implementation to see if they seem to match? Often discrepancies like this are due to different default settings, e.g., with one assuming the data is already centered or nromalized and one not.

@ Gregor Thomas, I was thinking this too, but the only arguments that seem to matter are alpha in R and support_fraction in Python. Unfortunately, setting these equal does not change anything. Only python allows for specifying whether or not the data are centered, and this also cannot explain the discrepancy. I'm stumped here...

Setting alpha and support_fraction both to 1 gets the outputs a lot closer (but still not identical, even though changing the seed doesn't seem to change the output for either).

While I'm guessing you're aware, just a reminder that the "robust covariance matrix" used in the minimum covariance determinant method is not the same as the "robust covariance matrix" used in e.g. "robust standard errors" and is not necessarily guaranteed any of the consistency, unbiasedness, or whatever that you get from some of the other estimators.

The software are not identical and so simply passing your data with the default arguments is not likely to produce identical results. The R function has extensive documentation of its arguments and default values but the Python function provides much less detail and so you may have to consult its source code to be absolutely sure of the cause. However, the parameters affecting estimation include at least the following, depending upon the R algorithm employed and your data (i.e. if the max steps are reached while solving):
Python

assume_centered
support_fraction
random_state

R

alpha
nsamp
nmini
scalefn
maxcsteps
initHsets
seed
tolSolve
use.correction
wgtFUN

As you can see, these do not clearly map to each other and this is especially problematic as the Python documentation omits equations needed to directly compare methods for e.g. determining subset size (at least without reading multiple articles).
What I'd recommend is pinpointing when the divergence arises. You said that it's not the centering (although I'd check this manually with pre-centered data). With MCD there appears to be a few possible points of divergence:

Sample selection: the method for determining which observations are used

Weighting: how those observations are weighted

Corrections: finite sample and consistency correction method

Algorithms: instructions passed to solver, method for solving the problem (e.g. "Fast MCD" vs. "DetMcd" in R)


The easiest starting place is to check the observations used. This is best in R and it looks like it is support in Python. If different observations were used, then you need to look at the number and size of samples checked for differences. If the same observations were used then I'd look at the raw estimates before re-weighting and correction. Python contains this (with raw_location_ and raw_covariance), and you appear able to either directly extract this in R (with raw.center and raw.cov). The R values for these may be post-correction (I doubt it), so you can also use raw.cnp2 to "uncorrect" the estimates if needed. If the estimates match then it's got to be the weighting or corrections.

Thanks! Looking at best in R and support_ in python gives me a very different list of observations used, so that must be the issue. What's weird though, is that setting the proportion of observations with support_fraction in python doesn't actually seem to control what proportion is used, it seems like it comes down to the random state.

I've looked into this a bit more, and it seems like the issue is two-fold. First off, like @socialscientist suggested, the list of observations used in python and R differs. The observations used in Python are completely controlled by the random state, while the R program attempts to find the "best" subset to compute the raw estimates. It's unclear to me how this is done, but it definitely differs from the python version.

Yeah, the Python docs are somewhat lacking. There's a note in the R docs that someone made a bunch of internal code into arguments for the function...perhaps Python is the initial implementation of it. All speculation.

I've looked into this a bit more, and it seems like the issue is two-fold.
First off, like @socialscientist suggested, the list of observations used in python and R differs. The observations used in Python are completely controlled by the random state, while the R program attempts to find the "best" subset to compute the raw estimates. It's unclear to me how this is done, but it definitely differs from the python version.
Secondly, and more importantly, I've found that in python, covariance_ = raw_covariance_. This is problematic, because the documentation makes it seem like covariance_ should be the corrected covariance matrix, but, apparently, it is not.
Instead, after initially fitting the data with mcd.fit(x), where x is the original data, you then need to execute mcd.correct_covariance(x) to apply the proper correction factor to the raw covariance matrix. Then, this newly corrected covariance matrix should be equivalent to cov in R.
I used best in R to find which subset of samples was being used in the calculation, and then I set up a loop to find which random state in python would give me an equivalent support_ in python:
def find_random_state(desired_indices, n_samples=20, n_selected=12):
    for random_state in range(1000000):  # limit search to the first 1,000,000 states
        rng = np.random.RandomState(random_state)
        # simulate random sampling
        selected_indices = rng.choice(n_samples, size=n_selected, replace=False)
        selected_indices.sort()
        if np.array_equal(selected_indices, desired_indices):
            return random_state
    return None

# desired indices
desired_indices = np.array([0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18])

random_state = find_random_state(desired_indices)
if random_state is not None:
    print(f"Found random state: {random_state}")
else:
    print("No random state found that matches the desired indices."

Then I used the identified random state (random_state=296910) in the following code:
# fit mcd
mcd = MinCovDet(random_state=296910).fit(x)

# calculate CORRECTED robust covariance matrix
x_cov = mcd.correct_covariance(x)

which yielded a result of:
x_cov = [[ 0.15645137  0.01036947 -0.04013162 -0.01179147]
         [ 0.01036947  0.09883205  0.03013766  0.08639141]
         [-0.04013162  0.03013766  0.06001058 -0.01768564]
         [-0.01179147  0.08639141 -0.01768564  0.16510918]]

This new result is more or less consistent with the R version:
x_cov =           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
        [1,]  0.15762177 0.01044705 -0.04043184 -0.01187968
        [2,]  0.01044705 0.09957141  0.03036312  0.08703770
        [3,] -0.04043184 0.03036312  0.06045952 -0.01781794
        [4,] -0.01187968 0.08703770 -0.01781794  0.16634435

A bit of a rabbit hole, but I figured I'd share what I found in case anyone else comes across this finicky problem in the future :)
